# How to use react-native-vision-camera for a small camera app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am facing issues while using the react-native-vision-camera package for a small camera app. I encountered an error while building the app on Android which says `"The Android Gradle plugin supports only kotlin-android-extensions Gradle plugin version 1.6.20 and higher.The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version: project ':react-native-vision-camera' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.30` and its failing my built on android."

I tried adding `"kotlinVersion = "1.7.0"` (under buildToolsVersion) to the `android/build.gradle` file but it gave me another error `"Error: EPERM: operation not permitted."` Running the commands as an administrator also did not work. I am using a Windows 10 machine with the latest version of Node.js and React Native.

Has anyone successfully set up the react-native-vision-camera package? I have followed the documentation but still facing these issues. It would be great if anyone could help me fix these errors and provide proper setup instructions.

Answer (score 12):

There is no need to change anything in **node_modules** (this is not very good).    It's simple enough in your **android/build.gradle** add

```
kotlinVersion = '1.6.20'
```

inside **buildscript->ext**

Answer (score 2):

Specify **kotlin version** inside **android/build.gradle** file

```
 kotlinVersion = "1.7.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

I went to this folders from the main app folder "node_modules/react-native-vision-camera/android/build.gradle"

def kotlin_version = '1.6.20'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

To solve this issue, you can try upgrading the Kotlin Gradle plugin version in the react-native-vision-camera project to version 1.6.20 or higher, which is supported by the Android Gradle plugin version you are using.

Go to node_modules/react-native-vision-camera/android/build.gradle

```
 dependencies {
           ....
           - classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
           + classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.20"
           ....
  }
```

**inside dependencies**

remove  *classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"*

add *classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.20"*